# Puppeteer - MaxListenerExceedsWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. page.close() and browser.close() not working

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await, puppeteer

I am currently using puppeteer library and having an issue with "MaxListenerExceedsWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected." error.

In my code, I am currently using page.close() as well as browser.close() but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Also, is there a way to kill the existing / already running puppeteer process?

Here is my code:

```
const scrapeData = async (url) => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();

   await page.goto(url);

   const currentPrice = await page.evaluate(() => {
      if(document.querySelectorAll('[data-test="product-price-reduced"]').length !== 0) {
        return document.querySelectorAll('[data-test="product-price-reduced"]')[0].textContent;
      } else {
        return document.querySelectorAll('[data-test="product-price"]')[0].textContent;
      }
   });

   const newSizes = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const sizeElements = document.getElementsByClassName('css-1uentg');
      const tempSizes = { currentAvailableSizes: [], unavailableSizes: [] };

      for(let i = 0; i < sizeElements.length; i++) {
        if(sizeElements[i].childNodes[0].hasAttribute('disabled') === false) {
           tempSizes.currentAvailableSizes.push(sizeElements[i].childNodes[1].textContent);
        } else {
           tempSizes.unavailableSizes.push(sizeElements[i].childNodes[1].textContent);
        }
      }
      return tempSizes;
  });

  const newProductInfo = { currentPrice, newSizes };

  await page.close();
  browser.disconnect();
  browser.close();

  return newProductInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"resolutions": {
  "@grpc/grpc-js": "0.5.2"
}
```

in your package.json file. Then you execute npx npm-force-resolutions and npm i.

It seems that the issue is affecting a lot of packages. Maybe it would be better to rollback (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/pull/1021) until it is fully resolved.